# PhpStorm - Node.js Core library activation error

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

I'm getting this error when I try to activate the Coding Assistance from NodeJS

> 2018-04-19 09:35:55,784 [4181746]   INFO - .NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator - configureAndAssociateWith(/usr/local/bin/node, 9.10.1) 
>   2018-04-19 09:35:55,792 [4181754]   INFO - .NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator - configure(/usr/local/bin/node, 9.10.1) 
>   2018-04-19 09:35:55,802 [4181764]   INFO - .NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator - Running /usr/local/bin/node --debug=50662 /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/plugins/NodeJS/js/node-core-modules/node-core-modules-loader.js assert buffer child_process cluster crypto dgram dns domain events fs http https net os path punycode querystring readline repl stream string_decoder tls tty url util vm zlib 
>   2018-04-19 09:35:55,954 [4181916]   INFO - .NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator - Process terminated with exit code 9 
>   2018-04-19 09:36:55,819 [4241781]   WARN - .NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator - Cannot configure Node.js Core library 
>   com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Cannot fetch core modules: timed out
>       at com.jetbrains.nodejs.library.NodeJsCoreSourcesFetchSession$MyProcessListener.awaitReady(NodeJsCoreSourcesFetchSession.java:314)
>       at com.jetbrains.nodejs.library.NodeJsCoreSourcesFetchSession.fetchSourcesSync(NodeJsCoreSourcesFetchSession.java:99)
>       at com.jetbrains.nodejs.library.NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator.configure(NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator.java:92)
>       at com.jetbrains.nodejs.library.NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator.access$000(NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator.java:45)
>       at com.jetbrains.nodejs.library.NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator$1.run(NodeJsCoreLibraryConfigurator.java:252)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:726)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$6.run(CoreProgressManager.java:410)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.a(ApplicationImpl.java:594)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$2.run(ApplicationImpl.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have correctly especified the node and npm libraries on Node Interpreter configuration.

Any sugesstions?

Comment: You must have some network related issue: *"Cannot fetch core modules: timed out at "*

Comment: How can I debug it?

Comment: what PhpStorm version do you use? Also, what is your Node.js version - is it 9.x?

Comment: what PhpStorm version do you use? Also, what is your Node.js version - is it 9.x?

Comment: I'm using PhpStorm 2017.1 and yes, node.js version is 9.11.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhpStorm 2017.1 is unlikely to work with Node.js 9.x. You should try either to downgrade Node.js (to 6.x for example) or to upgrade your IDE.